# Why is ubuntu 18.04.1 now more aggressively deleting packages?

Tags: apt, 18.04, ppa

Please bear with me, folks, as I am having a bit of difficulty explaining my issue. (And thus also searching for known solutions.)

Observed behavior: After a do-release-upgrade from ubuntu16 to 18.04.1, I found all my applications still intact, as has been the case in the past after LTS-to-LTS upgrades...

including Opera, which I had installed via ppa

Then I ran the script I have been using for years:

```
apt update -y
apt upgrade -y
apt dist-upgrade -y
apt-get autoremove -y
apt-get autoclean
```

...and suddenly Opera was gone.

I have now observed this behavior again, on a separate box (another u16-u18 upgrade), where a PPA-installed tool I use frequently ([GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM)) suddenly disappeared. In this case, however, it disappeared long after the upgrade (and numerous runnings of the above script).

Any insight will be much appreciated -- even if it is simply giving me better keywords whereby to look up more info.

Comment: PPAs were probably disabled so they're seeing orphaned packages and trying to clean them.  Also, however, if you haven't reenabled the PPA for your given release, the 'libraries' and 'dependencies' are probably out of date hence autoremove removes them.

Comment: `dist-upgrade` will attempt to solve problems...including by deleting packages. Using the -y flag disables the sensible precaution of asking if you really want to delete those packages. Stop using the -y flag and read the feedback until you feel that your system had settled a bit. Check your old apt logs for information about what got removed, when, and why.

Comment: @user535733  oh dear, do I feel silly. Thank you for the common sense.

Comment: Not silly at all. People become accustomed to routine, especially when the feedback for years has been quite dull an ignorable. Fresh set of eyes looking at the problem.